# How can I export a Room Database in Kotlin and send via email?

Tags: android, kotlin

I found the below SO question and have tried the options presented here. Looked for other solutions as well but for some reason, wanting to export the database seems to be an uncommon thing?
[Export Room database and attach to email Android Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68329072/export-room-database-and-attach-to-email-android-kotlin)

**Solution 1**

Opens the intent dialog and when I choose Gmail it briefly shows the attachment, then just shows a toast saying "Couldn't attach file."

**Solution 2**

Opens the intent dialog and when I choose Gmail then fails saying "Permission denied for the attachment".

For both these solutions if I try Google Drive it says unable to schedule file for upload.

In my manifest i tried adding

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

but that didn't change anything.

I am stuck on how to proceed here as the error is in Gmail/Drive and no logs show up for me to get a clue as to what the issue is!

I am working on a project that is using Honeywell `CT50` devices, and the latest version of Android that they support is `6.x` and I am wondering if that is causing my issues with this?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much reading and testing, I finally have a solution! In the exportDatabase function from Solution 2 from the first-mentioned link, I have changed from instead of using

```
val parent = File(activity.filesDir, "databases_temp")
val file = File(parent, "myDatabase")
```

I am now using the Downloads folder instead.

```
val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"databse_export.db")
```

getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is flagged as depreciated, but works.

The second change is to the provider_paths.xml file. Not sure if this was necessary or not?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Note: This has only been tested on Android 6!